# Fast create and add line in Linux Command line

Tags: linux, command-line

I need to check whether a file is on the system, if is it there I need to add a line to it. I have to do this in a script so I want this to be done without interruptions. Best way I can think of is like this:

```
sudo rm -rf /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list
sudo touch /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list
echo "deb https://apt.dockerproject.org/repo ubuntu-xenial main" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list
```

I am wondering if there is maybe a more elegant way to do this. I know the above works, but just wanted to know to extend my knowledge of the Linux command line.

Comment: why `rm`, `touch` and `tee -a` ? a simple`tee` would be enough.

Comment: Also, your example doesn't actually _check_ for anything, it just blindly overwrites the file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example is pretty messed-up. There are no checks and pointless commands. I'm also not sure why you say "append" to a file that you have just deleted.

Anyway, my approach would be to use to redirection operators. That is either `>` or `>>` like so:

To overwrite (or write a new file if the file is missing):

```
echo "string for file" > "/path/to/file"
```

To append to a file (will also create a new file if missing):

```
echo "string to append to file" >> "/path/to/file"
```

If you want to check if a file in on the system you can either use:

```
locate "filename"
```

or in a script you could do:

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ -f "/path/to/filename" ]
then
    echo "found filename"
else
    echo "filename is missing"
fi
```

I suggest you check `man [` and `man sh` (or `man bash`) for more examples.